# Docker Compose cannot connect to database

Tags: docker, docker-compose, typeorm, nestjs

I'm using nestjs for my backend and using typeorm as ORM.
I tried to define my database and my application in an docker-compose file.

If I'm running my database as a container and my application from my local machine it works well. My program connects and creates the tables etc.

But if I try to connect the database from within my container or to start the container with docker-compose up it fails.

Always get an ECONNREFUSED Error.

Where is my mistake ?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
volumes:
 dbdata:

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    volumes:
      - ./dbData/:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${TYPEORM_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${TYPEORM_USERNAME}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${TYPEORM_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - ${TYPEORM_PORT}:5432

  backend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    command: npm run start
    volumes:
      - .:/src
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.5

WORKDIR /home

# Bundle app source
COPY . /home

# Install app dependencies
#RUN npm install -g nodemon
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production
RUN npm i -g @nestjs/cli
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
```

.env

```
# .env
HOST=localhost
PORT=3000
NODE_ENV=development
LOG_LEVEL=debug

TYPEORM_CONNECTION=postgres
TYPEORM_HOST=localhost
TYPEORM_USERNAME=postgres
TYPEORM_PASSWORD=postgres
TYPEORM_DATABASE=mariokart
TYPEORM_PORT=5432
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE=true
TYPEORM_DROP_SCHEMA=true
TYPEORM_LOGGING=all
TYPEORM_ENTITIES=src/database/entity/*.ts
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS=src/database/migrations/**/*.ts
TYPEORM_SUBSCRIBERS=src/database/subscribers/**/*.ts
```

I tried to use links but it don't work in the container.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at your `/etc/hosts` inside the `backend` container. You will see

```
192.0.18.1    dir_db_1
```

or something like that. The IP will be different and `dir` will represent the dir you're in. Therefore, you must change `TYPEORM_HOST=localhost` to `TYPEORM_HOST=dir_db_1`.

Although, I suggest you set static names to your containers.

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: project_db
    ...
  backend:
    container_name: project_backend
```

In this case you can always be sure, that your container will have a static name and you can set `TYPEORM_HOST=project_db` and never worry about the name ever again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a network and share among two services.

Create network for db and backend services:

```
networks:
  common-net: {}
```

and add the network to these two services. So your .yml file would like below after edit:

```
version: '3.1'
volumes:
 dbdata:

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    volumes:
      - ./dbData/:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${TYPEORM_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${TYPEORM_USERNAME}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${TYPEORM_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - ${TYPEORM_PORT}:5432
    networks:
      - common-net

  backend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    command: npm run start
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    networks:
      - common-net


networks:
  common-net: {}
```

###### Note1: After this change, there is no need to expose the Postgres port externally unless you have a reason for it. You can remove that section.

###### Note2: TYPEORM_HOST should be renamed to db. Docker would resolve the IP address of db service by itself.

Comment: doesn't docker compose create a common network for the containers by default ?

Comment: Yes! You're right. Changing the typeorm_hostname will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I had the same issue and I was able to figure out a solution.
Basically, my backend was a nestjs application and the datatbase was postgresql.

I included the environment variables in the nestjs application and it started to work fine.
Below is the docker-compose file that worked for me.

```
version: '0.0.1'
services:
  postgresdb:
    container_name: postgresdb
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
      - POSTGRES_DB=dummy_db
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
  web:
    image: server01:tag01
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=postgresdb
```