# Connect to a local PostgreSQL database from a docker-compose service

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

#### Context

I need to connect from inside a compose service to a PostgreSQL (10) database which is on my local host machine (Ubuntu 18.04).

#### Description of the errors

I have set `service > app > build >` to `network: host` in my compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
  app:
    image: myservice:0.0.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      network: host
```

The Dockerfile is build `FROM python:3.9.1-slim-buster`.

Then, from inside my compose service (`docker exec -it composefilefolder_app_1 bash`) I try to connect to a PostgreSQL database on the host machine with `psycopg2` (after having started `python`):

```
import psycopg2 

DBPARAMS = {
    'user': 'postgres',
    'password': 'password',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': '5432',
    'dbname': 'mydatabase'
}

conn = psycopg2.connect(**DBPARAMS)
```

but this returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Then I tried to use my host machine IP (given by `ifconfig`):

```
import psycopg2 

DBPARAMS = {
    'user': 'postgres',
    'password': 'password',
    'host': '192.168.x.1',
    'port': '5432',
    'dbname': 'mydatabase'
}

conn = psycopg2.connect(**DBPARAMS)
```

but now I got a time-out after one minute:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "192.168.x.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

All other parameters are correct as I can connect to this database by running the same command from the host machine directly.

#### Question

How can I connect to my host machine PostgreSQL database from my compose service?

#### What else I've tried

1. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313852/docker-compose-cannot-connect-to-database) thread seemed promising but it doesn't work either.
2. And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350843/how-to-connect-from-docker-compose-to-host-postgresql) is for Mac users.
3. I also tried to set `list_adressess='*'` in my local machine `postgres.conf` file AND to set `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` into the `pg_hba.conf` file without any changes. But if I can avoid to tweak my local PostgreSQL config that would be great.
4. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container) thread also did not help as it makes use of my local machine IP, for which the connection is timing-out as I said.

Comment: You say that you can connect on the host machine directly. It's likely to be a firewall blocking you from accessing it from another machine. Have you opened the port?

Comment: All this is happening on the same local computer (laptop), which I called my 'host machine'.

Comment: I think I'm out of my depth. Probably not helpful, but I'm thinking of docker `EXPOSE`. Again, probably not helpful, but that's what sprung to mind

Comment: https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#expose probably not relevant (it goes the other way out the container) if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Can you please share the whole content of `docker-compose.yml` file?